# generate header and trailer after splitting files

Tags: unix, awk, split

This is coding that I already do splitting:

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\, '
    BEGIN{OFS=","}
    NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
    { 
        gsub(/"/, "", $1); 
        file="Assgmt_"$1"_"DATE".csv"; 
        print (a[file]++?"":h ORS) $0 > file
    }
' Test_01012020.CSV
```

but then, how can I add some header and trailer into above command?

Comment: Which is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is Assgmt_"$1"_"DATE".csv @JoseRicardoBustosM.

Comment: I ask for the format you want in the header and trailer

Comment: I just want to put 01012017 for header meaning that date and for trailer I want to put EOF @JoseRicardoBustosM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you,

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\, '
    BEGIN{OFS=","}
    NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
    { 
        gsub(/"/, "", $1); 
        file="Assgmt_"$1"_"DATE".csv";
        print (a[file]++?"":DATE ORS h ORS) $0 > file
    }
    END{for(file in a) print "EOF" > file}
' Test_01012020.CSV
```

Comment: It helps me a lot! thank you :) but the date is automatically right? Can I just put specific date example 01012015? so that it will not appear automatic but we can set it? **I just thinking about that** @JoseRicardoBustosM.

Comment: sure .... `"01012015" ORS h ORS` instead of `DATE ORS h ORS` for example